# How to use a JavaFX binding to disable a button if TextField has invalid input

Tags: javafx

I got the following code from [The Definitive Guide to Modern Java Clients with JavaFX](https://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484249253):

```
updateButton.disableProperty()
    .bind(listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull()
            .or(wordTextField.textProperty().isEmpty())
            .or(definitionTextArea.textProperty().isEmpty()));
```

I would like to modify it so the button is disabled if the String entered into `frequencyTextField` is not a nonnegative integer. I added a term to the conjunction as shown:

```
updateButton.disableProperty()
    .bind(listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull()
            .or(isLegalFrequency(frequencyTextField.textProperty()).not())
            .or(wordTextField.textProperty().isEmpty())
            .or(definitionTextArea.textProperty().isEmpty()));
```

Although it is probably not relevant, here is the method that tests validity:

```
    private BooleanProperty isLegalFrequency(StringProperty sp) {
        System.out.println("isLegalFrequency(" + sp.get() + ")");
        try {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(sp.get());
            return new SimpleBooleanProperty(value >= 0);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that the button is always disabled. I have established that `isLegalFrequency()` is called only once, when the scene is being created. This makes sense, since I am passing `frequencyTextField.textProperty()`, not calling a method on it (which presumably sets up a listener behind the scenes).

Is there a way to modify the program *without adding an explicit listener* so it behaves as I'd like, or is it necessary to create a `ChangeListener` on `frequencyTextField.textProperty`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very generally, you can create an arbitrary method:

```
private Boolean validate() {
    // arbitrary implementation here...
    // in your case something like
    if (listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null) return false ;
    if (wordTextField.getText().isEmpty()) return false ;
    if (definitionTextArea.getText().isEmpty()) return false ;
    if (! isLegalFrequency(frequencyTextField.getText())) return false ;
    return true ;
}
```

and then do

```
updateButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
    () -> ! validate(),
    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty(),
    frequencyTextField.textProperty(),
    wordTextField.textProperty(),
    definitionTextArea.textProperty()));
```

The parameters to the `createBooleanBinding()` method are a `Callable<Boolean>` (i.e. a method taking no parameters and returning a `Boolean`) followed by zero or more instances of `javafx.beans.Observable` (any property or `ObservableList`, etc, will work). You should include any property (or other observable) here that should trigger a recalculation of the `disableProperty()` when it changes.